# How to convert convex hull points to real coordinates in image

Tags: opencv

I must totally misunderstand something. I am using following code to find corner points of a quadrilateral

```
    maxCtr = cvApproxPoly( maxCtr, sizeof(CvContour), mem2, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 5, 1 );
    CvSeq* hull = cvConvexHull2( maxCtr, 0, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0 );
    int numOfHull =hull->total;
    CvPoint*  hullPoints;
    hullPoints = ( CvPoint *)malloc((hull->total)*sizeof(CvSeq));
    cvCvtSeqToArray(hull,hullPoints);
```

It's working well to find the shape correctly as I verified with cvDrawContours. But when I looked at the `hullPoints` expecting them to be coordinates of four corners, their x and y values look crazy such as 83603736, 83603744. Is this normal? If so, how can I get their coordinates of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a problem here at the fifth line:

```
hullPoints = ( CvPoint *)malloc((hull->total)*sizeof(CvSeq));
```

Should be:

```
hullPoints = ( CvPoint *)malloc((hull->total)*sizeof(CvPoint));
```

Comment: That is a mistake on my side in copy & paste. But I am not sure that's the reason because memory wrongly allocated is not necessarily equal to wrong values. I am having wrong values. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: You could check if CvPoint pt = **CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM( CvPoint*, hull, i ); where 0 <= i < numOfHull, gives you the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `convexHull` function call:

```
cvConvexHull2( maxCtr, 0, CV_CLOCKWISE, 0 )
```

When the last parameter *return_points* set to **zero**, the function will give you the indices of the points, not the points themselves

To make this work, I think you should just replace the last parameter with **one** to be able to get the points.